# Page binding in ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I'm trying to make a window which displays unknown number of pages within based on collection passed to builder.

Concept seemed rather simple to me - make a template Page, create collection of pages during initialization and display them though ItemControl. So:

Data Context Class:

```
class CollectionDetailsWindowContext
{
    public List<EntityDetailsPage> Pages { get; }

    public CollectionDetailsWindowContext(Collection _collection)
    {
        Pages = new List<EntityDetailsPage>();

        foreach (var entity in _collection.Entities)
            Pages.Add(new EntityDetailsPage(entity));
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Pages}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Frame Content="{Binding .}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

If i run this code it results in following exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Page can have only Window or Frame as parent.'
```

When i try to do all bindings manually without ItemControl (so,picking first few Entites from Collection and binding them to frames), everything works fine, which leads me to believe that the way ItemControl passes Page to frame is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so, a couple of things here.

First, the conventional approach is to separate the data and the view. If you google "MVVM" or "MVC" you will see a ton about this. Personally I recommend MVVM. So you wouldn't usually have a page that binds to other pages. The displayed page (the "view") should bind to the data (well, to a "view model" representing the data), not other pages.

Second, Pages are typically displayed in Frames using NavigateTo. You could have a StackPanel containing Frames and then load a Page into each Frame, but it seems like overkill. It would be more direct to just have a ListView and a template for the details. If you have multiple types of detail then you could use a DataTemplateSelector within the list view.

Third, eventually you will probably want to update the data, for which purpose you will need a collection that notifies the view about the changes to the selected list of entity details. This is the view model for the list. Also each entity (EntityDetail in your case) should notify it's properties on the UI thread (or have a separate view model object that does so), but I won't get too far into that here. Again I am talking about the conventional way of doing things, of course there are many other ways as well.

So... something like this perhaps:

```
partial class DetailsPage {
    public ObservableCollection<EntityDetail> EntityDetails {get;}

    public DetailsPage( ObservableCollection<EntityDetail> entityDetails) {
        this.EntityDetails = entityDetails;
    } 
}

<Page
    x:Class="DetailsPage"
    …
    >
    <Page.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="EntityDetailDataTemplate" x:DataType="local:EntityDetail">
                <TextBlock Text={x:Bind Name, Mode=OneWay}/> (assuming Name is a property in EntityDetail)
            </DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Page.Resources>
    <ListView
        ItemsSource={x:Bind EntityDetails, Mode=OneWay}
        ItemTemplate={StaticResource EntityDetailDataTemplate}
        …
        >
    </ListView>
</Page>
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right regarding MVVM approach, and in the end of the day i'm probably going to switch to  it. For now however my main issue with using DataTemplates is that Page for EntityDetails is fairly complex (1800-2000 lines of xaml) and modifying it without designer to observe immediate effects of changes is rather troublesome. I wish i could accept both yours and mm8's answer.

Comment: There are different views on what one should do when something is "a bit messed up" in one's code. Personally if it is a significant change them I prefer to fix it up front rather than let it go. Otherwise I just end up digging the hole deeper.

Comment: @JagdCrab, one other thought. If you really want to bond to a list of pages, you could drive from Frame, add a Page property and navigate to the Page whenever it changes. Then in your view you could use a ListView and use this Frame-derived class in the DataTemplate.

Answer (score 1):

> ...which leads me to believe that the way ItemControl passes Page to frame is the issue.

The reason why your code doesn't work is that the `ItemTemplate` is not applied to `UIElements` such as `Pages`.

You could fix this by creating your own custom `ItemsControl` and override the `IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride` method:

```
public class FrameItemsControl : ItemsControl
{
    protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The default implementation returns `(item is UIElement)`.

**Usage:**

```
<local:FrameItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Pages}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Frame Content="{Binding .}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</local:FrameItemsControl>
```

Comment: @JagdCrab: Did you try my suggestion?